# Evitar hacer doble clic en un botón

Tags: c#, asp.net

Compañeros he estado intentando probar en varios códigos del internet y ninguno me funciona, cómo puedo evitar que el usuario no haga doble click en un botón en asp.net C#, ya que al agregar el botón el usuario tiene que hacer click dos veces para mandar llamar otro formulario y sólo quiero una vez.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

       Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest (BeginRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) { var oControl =args.get_postBackElement(); oControl.disabled = true; } </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Sigue sin funcionar, tengo que dar dos veces click, no estoy usando jquery ni javascript, sólo agregué esas líneas de código

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo algunos que me funcionaron

http://tgynther.blogspot.com/2011/07/aspnet-prevent-button-double-click.html

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, null) + ";");
```

**Esta otra tambien me funciono**

El script

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function DisableButton() {
      document.getElementById("<%=Button1.ClientID %>").disabled = true;
  }
  window.onbeforeunload = DisableButton;
  </script>
```

y en el boton

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Clicked" />
```